# Как выполнять несколько разных скриптов с одной БД SQLite и одним файлом конфига

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, yaml

Делаю пет-проект на Python, и возникла необходимость создания нескольких идентичных скриптов (парсит просто разные ссылки по единому алгоритму), но они работают с единой базой SQLite и подтягивают конфиги из одного YAML файла.

Прошу совета по вопросам:
Я все это дело хочу выложить на сервер. Как это все грамотно завернуть в докер и крутить по крону? Все скрипты должны будут запускаться в одно и то же время.

Еще вопрос, скрипты с параллельным запросом в БД и конфиг нормально отработают?
На тестах получилось так, что при работе одного скрипта, второй выбивал ошибку при доступе к конфигам.

Comment: Какую именно ошибку выбивало и почему её текста нет в вопросе? )

Comment: My bad... Не сохранял нигде, пару раз получил и забил. Как будет возможность, закину

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не советовал использовать параллельные запросы в SQLite, [можно цитату из доков?](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

> ...SQLite будет работать через сетевую файловую систему, но из-за
> задержек, связанных с большинством сетевых файловых систем,
> производительность будет не очень высокой. Кроме того, во многих
> реализациях сетевых файловых систем (как на Unix, так и на Windows)
> логика блокировки файлов работает с ошибками. Если блокировка файлов
> работает некорректно, два или более клиентов могут попытаться
> одновременно изменить одну и ту же часть одной и той же базы данных,
> что приведет к ее повреждению...

Comment: Да, так то `SQLite` не многопоточный, он вообще простенький и для использования в одно лицо.

Comment: Как вариант - могу просто запускать скрипты по очереди

Comment: Да, я так и хотел сказать, если использование не монопольное, лучше использовать клиент-серверную базу данных, там по ссылке еще несколько проблем описано, связанными с блокировками.

Comment: @Brain of Мadness можно по очереди, но еще обратить внимание на размер, они хоть и пишут ` limited in size to 281 terabytes` , но с размером будет уменьшатся скорость.